# Django Get value of form field in Update View

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am using class based views and want to get the current value of a given field `ward` in my UpdateView's `get_context_data` method. I've tried using the `get` method but it isn't working. Here's my method:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ApplicationUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['money_per_ward'] = int(getattr(Allocation.objects.first(), 'amount_allocated') / 30)

    context['ward'] = self.request.POST.get('ward') # <-- This prints "None"
    return context
```

My full UpdateView:

```
class ApplicationUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Application
    form_class = ApplicationForm
    success_message = "Details Updated Successfully"
    extra_context = {
        'title' : 'Edit Application Details'
    }




    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ApplicationUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['money_per_ward'] = int(getattr(Allocation.objects.first(), 'amount_allocated') / 30)
        context['ward'] = self.request.POST.get('ward')
        return context
```

And my urls.py:

```
path('apply/', default_views.ApplicationCreateView.as_view(), name='apply'),
path('applications/<int:pk>/update/', default_views.ApplicationUpdateView.as_view(), name='edit_application'),
```

and my template:

```
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            {% if  title == 'Apply' %}
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Apply For Bursary</legend>
            {% elif title == 'Edit Application Details' %}
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Edit details for {{application.full_name}}
            </legend>
            {% else %}
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"></legend>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h5 class="border-bottom mb-4">Personal Details</h5>
                    <div class="border-bottom mb-4">
                    {{ form.full_name|as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ form.gender|as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ form.parent_name|as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ form.contact|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>

                    <h5 class="border-bottom mb-4">School Details</h5>
                    {{ form.category|as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ form.school_name|as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ form.adm_number|as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ form.year|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h5 class="border-bottom mb-4">Location Details</h5>
                    {{ form.subcounty|as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ form.ward|as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ form.sublocation|as_crispy_field }}
                    <small class="text-muted">Money: {{money_per_ward}} {{ward}}</small>
                    {{ form.is_qualified|as_crispy_field}}

                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-outline-info" name="submit" type="submit">
                {% if title == 'Apply' %}
                Submit Application
                {% else %}
                Update Details
                {% endif %}
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Is there a way I can access the current value of this field `{{form.ward|as_crispy_field}}`?

Comment: Where do you want to use this in POST or GET request?

Comment: Also share the entire view and the corresponding url.

Comment: @AtleyVarghese My Form uses POST method but now in my Update View I want to get the current value of that particular field.

Comment: on Form submit right?

Comment: Not on form submit. When the form is loaded. That is, when I load my UpdateView URL @AtleyVarghese

Comment: The get_context_data() is used to send context to template it is called during a GET request.

Comment: During a GET request self.request.POST will be empty

Comment: When a form is initially loaded it is a get request the only way to get values to get content function is from url kwargs or from database.

Comment: How do you plan to send the ward valu to the view in GET request

Comment: I intend to use the value of that particular ward to filter some query and then throw the result back to the template @AtleyVarghese

Comment: Also note the updated changes in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189044/discussion-between-atley-varghese-and-abedy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Bad. I only needed to use the `self.get_object()` method.

Here's the working solution:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ApplicationUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['money_per_ward'] = int(getattr(Allocation.objects.first(), 'amount_allocated') / 30)
    context['ward'] = self.get_object().ward # <-- Now this works perfectly
    return context
```